# Is the given usage of Outrage is correct?

Tags: word-usage

**Outrage in my mind, Smile on my face. This is Life**.

Can outrage be used the way I used above?

Comment: That looks like a poem, or haiku.  Normal rules don't apply.  (Also, I think I like it)

Comment: Just thought of the line :) So this seems fine..

Comment: If it is not poetry, you might avoid capitalizing *smile* and *life*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just omitted an implicit "There is" to the first two clauses. Ok, "There is a" for the second clause.  In the right context, that is fine and even an improvement.